# Dynamic column/attribute. Stuck. Need inspiration

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

i’m looking for a solution to a problem that I’m having for a while now. Maybe you can inspire me to do this better. I’m trying not to make a basic mistake in the planning process therefore I’m asking you for advice.

I’m having a Contact::model which has few fixed attributes like id etc. Additionally I would like to have different attributes created dynamically for the whole Contact::model. Some user will be given the functionality to add attributes like name, email, address to the whole model. I’ve dropped the idea of programmatically updating the table itself by creating/dropping columns (this would introduce different problems). As for now i've created two additional tables. One with the additional column names [Columns::model] and a pivot table to assign the value to a Contact::model and Column::model.

To list all contacts i’m preparing the ContactColumn table as array where the first key is the contact_id and the second is the column_id, therefore i get the value. This introduces the n+1 issue. This would not be that bad, but with this approach it will be extremely hard (or resource consuming) to order the contacts by dynamic column values, filtering, searching etc.

Can you somehow guide me to a better solution. How can i merge the contact collection with the values for given columns so it looks like it was a fixed table?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Fixed columns [i.e. ID]</th>
            @foreach ($columns as $column)
                <th>{{ $column->name }}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($contacts as $contact)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $contact->id }}</td>
                @foreach ($columns as $column)
                    <td>
                        @if (array_key_exists($column->id, $values[$contact->id]))
                            {{ $values[$contact->id][$column->id] }}
                        @endif
                    </td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the `$value` array.

```
foreach (ColumnContact::all() as $pivot) {
    $values[$pivot->contact_id][$pivot->column_id] = $pivot->value;
}

return $values;
```

Edit: I've solved it like this

```
$this->contacts = Contact::when($this->dynamicColumnName, function($query) {
    $query->join('column_contact', function ($join) {
        $join->on('id', '=', 'column_contact.contact_id')
            ->where('column_contact.column_id', '=', $this->dynamicColumnName->id);
        })
        ->orderBy('value', $this->orderingDirection);
    })
    (...)
    ->paginate(self::PER_PAGE);
```

Comment: Have you considered just adding a json column with custom user data?

Comment: I'm not sure if this solves my problems with sorting and filtering and the data in one cell can get very big.

Comment: You can sort by or filter by JSON queries as described in https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses as for size I think JSON columns for MySQL can be as big as 2GB. You can also use a JSON column to create virtual secondary fields and indexes as described in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The more i read and research on JSON queries the more i wan to test this and i think this could be the solution. Thank you. Additionally i was advised on this: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-schemaless-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fixed fields, add an extra JSON field in your schema called 'custom_fields'. Have a look into => https://github.com/stancl/virtualcolumn

Separate table for custom fields is not a good idea because then you have to handle model events separately and so on.

Comment: I will test this out. Thank you for the idea.